# How do I store user defined values in wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

I am new to chatbots and using the wit.ai.
I had like to store user defined values for future use, such as Name of the user.
When the user says his name. It gets stored in a variable that can be used later.
Using entities limits me to a predefined list of names.

Answer (score 2):

They have changed the [getting started](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart) guide. Initially they showed the way to store user queries.

What you want to use is `context` object. It can store information which you want to pass on for later use. It is used to save the state of conversation.

In your story, click on `Bot Executes`, then an action to be executed at backend and finally type the variable name like `username` in the `update context keys with` field. This will make `username` available for use.